# Marklogic xdmp.rollback() : Cannot read property 'result' of null

Tags: javascript, transactions, marklogic, rollback, acid

I was trying to understand the rollback function in ServerSide JavaScript. I was running the below JavaScript query, which I got from the MarkLogic documentation for [`xdmp.rollback()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.rollback) and I got the error as

> [javascript] TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of null.

Query:

```
declareUpdate({explicitCommit: true});
xdmp.documentInsert("/docs/first.json", {"first": 1});
xdmp.documentInsert("/docs/second.json", {"second": 2});
xdmp.rollback();
```

Result:

> [javascript] TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of null

Whereas I tried running XQuery function for rollback [`xdmp:rollback()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:rollback) which works fine without throwing an error. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample does work. If you execute it, you will notice that those documents are not inserted into the database. You can add some diagnostic `xdmp.log()` messages and look for them in the ErrorLog to prove that it is executing your code.

It would appear that when executing the code via Query Console, the result of the eval execution is not the complete/expected payload.

> When a transaction is rolled back, the current statement immediately terminates, updates made by any statement in the transaction are discarded, and the transaction terminates.
>
> The result of a statement terminated with `xdmp:rollback` is always the empty sequence.

So, rather than returning a response object with a `result` property, the eval response is `null`, and an attempt to access the `result` property result in an exception that bubbles up.

If you execute the following code:

```
declareUpdate({explicitCommit: true});
xdmp.commit();
```

a response like the following is returned to Query Console:

```
{
 "elapsedCurrent":0.605, 
 "elapsedDiff":-0.307, 
 "isSequence":false, 
 "resultCount":1, 
 "results":[{"type":"Null", "result":"null"}]
}
```

But when executing the example code from the `xdmp.rollback()` page, the following response is returned, and what you are seeing is that `errorcode` displayed in the Query Console results panel:

```
{
  "error":{
    "evalinfo":"query evaluated as JavaScript", 
    "errorcode":"[javascript] TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of null", 
    "stacktrace":{"stack":[]}
  }
}
```